# Inconsistency between FourierTrigSeries and FourierCosCoefficient

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have the following function defined for a quasi-square wave:

```
Clear[x, f, T, s, s0];
f = 60;
T = 1/f;

sa[x_] := 
 Which[x > 2*Pi, s0[Mod[x, 2*Pi]], x < 0, s0[Mod[x, 2*Pi]], 
  0 < x < 2*Pi, s0[x]]
s0[x_] := Piecewise[{{0, x < Pi/6}, {1, Pi/6 < x < 5*Pi/6}, {0, 
     5*Pi/6 < x < 7*Pi/6}, {-1, 7*Pi/6 < x < 11*Pi/6}, {0, 
     11*Pi/6 < x < 2*Pi}}];

Plot[{sa[2*Pi*f*x], sa[2*Pi*f*x - 2*Pi/3], sa[2*Pi*f*x + 2*Pi/3], 
  Sin[2*Pi*f*x], Sin[2*Pi*f*x - 2*Pi/3], 
  Sin[2*Pi*f*x + 2*Pi/3]}, {x, -0*T, 1*T}]
```

[image: Plot]

The plot shows three quasi-square waveforms time-shifted by multiples of $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. When I calculate the Fourier series for $s_a(2\pi ft)$, I get the following output:

```
a = FourierTrigSeries[sa[2*Pi*f*x], x, 7, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, 2 Pi/T}]
```

> $\frac{2 \sqrt{3} \sin (120 \pi  x)}{\pi }-\frac{2 \sqrt{3} \sin (600 \pi  x)}{5 \pi }-\frac{2 \sqrt{3} \sin (840 \pi  x)}{7 \pi }$

which shows only odd harmonics without triplen harmonics. This is expected.

However, when I try to calculate the FourierCosCoefficient, I get the following expression for the code snippet:

```
aSa[n_]=FourierCosCoefficient[sa[2*Pi*f*x], x, n, 
 FourierParameters -> {1, 2 Pi/T}]
```

> $\frac{2 \left(\sin \left(\frac{5 \pi  n}{6}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{6}\right)\right)}{\pi  n}$

which gives:

```
aSa[2] // FullSimplify
```

> $-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\pi }$

This implies that an even harmonic exists at $2f$, which is inconsistent with the first result from the Fourier series.

Could someone please explain what is causing this or what I am doing wrong? I am confused about the usage of FourierParameters.

Answer (score 3):

It is because `FourierCosCoefficient` or `FourierCosSeries` assumes the function is even.

[image]

You can ca see it in the definition of coefficients of `FourierTrigSeries` where integral is taken over interval `(-Pi,Pi)`.

[image]

while for `FourierCosSeries` the interval of integration is `(0,Pi)` and coefficient is multiplied by `2` (i.e. it is assumed function is even).

[image]